# I cannot set use chown and change permission to www-data :www-data

Tags: web-hosting, http-status-code-403, permission-denied, chown

I'm confused about those file permissions.now my website is suffering a forbidden access when i try to get access from the url. and I find out that the ownership in my FTP is set to myusername/myusername, and I was told to set it to www-data:www-data in order for public to view your website. I tried the following command

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /public_html
```

And it says

```
chown: invalid user: `www-data:www-data'
```

How can i set the file permission to www-data:www-data and what does it mean for setting it to www-data:www-data and what is the different between myusername:www-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the error message you get when you *have* no `www-data` user (if the user is okay but the group is bad, it complains about the group):

```
pax> chown -R x:x qq.cpp           # Bad user and group
chown: invalid user: `x:x'

pax> chown -R pax:pax qq.cpp       # Good user and group

pax> chown -R pax:x qq.cpp         # Good user, bad group
chown: invalid group: `pax:x'
```

So that'd be the first thing I'd be checking, that the user actually exists:

```
grep www-data /etc/passwd
```

I think you may find that some set-ups have the `www-data` group, and you're meant to add whatever users that need access to that group. You can certainly *create* a `www-data` user and add that to the group but I don't think it's mandatory.

---

And, as an aside, this is not setting the *permissions,* that's done with `chmod` and is a separate issue. The `chown` command merely sets up the file ownership (and groupship, for want of a better word).

Comment: I haven't set the www-data user yet, should i set it manually?

Comment: @KesongXie, if you haven't yet created the `www-data` user, that's certainly why your `chown` is failing. The user must exist first so that its UID can be obtained for the files you're changing.